# Traversing through XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, .net-core, xmldocument

I have the following XML file:

```
<Tournament TeamPlayers="1">
    <Teams>
        <Team>
            <TeamID>0</TeamID>
            <TeamName>Sample</TeamName>
            <Status>10</Status>
            <Memo>Sample Team</Memo>
            <ByeRounds>0</ByeRounds>
            <Players>
                <Player>
                    <MemberNumber>1</MemberNumber>
                    <MemberName>Dummy</MemberName>
                    <PlayerFirstName>Test</PlayerFirstName>
                    <PlayerLastName>User</PlayerLastName>
                    <SeatOrder>A</SeatOrder>
                </Player>
                <Player>
                    <MemberNumber></MemberNumber>
                    <MemberName></MemberName>
                    <PlayerFirstName></PlayerFirstName>
                    <PlayerLastName></PlayerLastName>
                    <SeatOrder>B</SeatOrder>
                </Player>
                <Player>
                    <MemberNumber></MemberNumber>
                    <MemberName></MemberName>
                    <PlayerFirstName></PlayerFirstName>
                    <PlayerLastName></PlayerLastName>
                    <SeatOrder>C</SeatOrder>
                </Player>
            </Players>
        </Team>
    </Teams>
</Tournament>
```

The idea is that I loop through the `<Players>` block and add the data there to a holder of class data. However, when I run the following code, which looks like it is yielding the contents of the Inner Players field, VS stops warning that it is empty:

```
    Dim teamNodes As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Tournament/Teams/Team")
    Dim lstOutputTeams As New List(Of TournamentTeam)

    ' Check the atrribute of "TeamPlayers" in the root. 
    'Dim intExpectedPlayers As Integer = xmlDoc.Attributes("/").Value
    Dim intExpectedPlayers As Integer = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Tournament").Attributes("TeamPlayers").Value

    For Each node As XmlNode In teamNodes

        Dim tpPlayerA As New PlayerInfo
        Dim tpPlayerB As New PlayerInfo
        Dim tpPlayerC As New PlayerInfo

        Dim playerNodes As XmlNodeList = node.SelectNodes("Players")

        For Each innerNode As XmlNode In playerNodes
            Dim tpPlayer As PlayerInfo = New PlayerInfo With {
                .strMembershipName = innerNode.SelectSingleNode("MemberName").InnerText,
                .strMembershipNo = innerNode.SelectSingleNode("MemberNumber").InnerText,
                .strPlayerFirstName = innerNode.SelectSingleNode("PlayerFirstName").InnerText,
                .strPlayerLastName = innerNode.SelectSingleNode("PlayerLastName").InnerText,
                .strSeatOrder = innerNode.SelectSingleNode("SeatOrder").InnerText
            }

            Select Case tpPlayer.strSeatOrder
                Case "A"
                    tpPlayerA = tpPlayer
                Case "B"
                    tpPlayerB = tpPlayerB
                Case "C"
                    tpPlayerC = tpPlayerC
            End Select
        Next

        lstOutputTeams.Add(New TournamentTeam() With {
                           .strTeamName = node.SelectSingleNode("TeamName").InnerText,
                           .intTeamID = node.SelectSingleNode("TeamID").InnerText,
                           .intByeRounds = node.SelectSingleNode("ByeRounds").InnerText,
                           .intStatus = node.SelectSingleNode("Status").InnerText,
                           .strMemo = node.SelectSingleNode("Memo").InnerText,
                           .tpPlayerA = tpPlayerA,
                           .tpPlayerB = tpPlayerB,
                           .tpPlayerC = tpPlayerC}
                           )
    Next
```

In particular, the error is: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`. I'm not sure where the null reference is taking place. (The breakpoint places it at the `Dim tpPlayer As Player Info` line.

Comment: You don't appear to need to recursively navigate the document. There's nothing there that appear to be recursive? Also, you should be using `XDocument` these days.

Comment: This is only sample data. There may be multiple of each child (teams, penalty, and staff) in the actual live data.

Comment: Also I literally just finished writing this as XmlDocument as I was struggling with XDocument. :/

Comment: `XDocument` is so much easier. I still don't understand why this is recursive, and if it is, then your sample should show that otherwise it makes it difficult for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be causing you grief that your `Select Case` is assigning variables to themselves:

```
Select Case tpPlayer.strSeatOrder
    Case "A"
        tpPlayerA = tpPlayer
    Case "B"
        tpPlayerB = tpPlayerB
    Case "C"
        tpPlayerC = tpPlayerC
End Select
```

The RHS of each should just be `tpPlayer`.

You caused this bug by doing this:

```
    Dim tpPlayerA As New PlayerInfo
    Dim tpPlayerB As New PlayerInfo
    Dim tpPlayerC As New PlayerInfo
```

You should have done this instead:

```
    Dim tpPlayerA As PlayerInfo
    Dim tpPlayerB As PlayerInfo
    Dim tpPlayerC As PlayerInfo
```

Here's what your code would look like with `XDocument`. It's much cleaner.

```
    Dim intExpectedPlayers As Integer = CInt(xd.Root.Attribute("TeamPlayers"))
    
    Dim lstOutputTeams As List(Of TournamentTeam) = _
    ( _
        From team In xd.Root.Element("Teams").Elements("Team") _
        Let players = team.Element("Players").Elements("Player").Select(Function(player) _
            New PlayerInfo() With _
            {
                .strMembershipName = player.Element("MemberName").Value,
                .strMembershipNo = player.Element("MemberNumber").Value,
                .strPlayerFirstName = player.Element("PlayerFirstName").Value,
                .strPlayerLastName = player.Element("PlayerLastName").Value,
                .strSeatOrder = player.Element("SeatOrder").Value
            }).ToDictionary(Function(x) x.strSeatOrder) _
        Select New TournamentTeam() With _
        {
            .intTeamID = CInt(team.Element("TeamID")),
            .strTeamName = CStr(team.Element("TeamName")),
            .intStatus = CInt(team.Element("Status")),
            .strMemo = CStr(team.Element("Memo")),
            .intByeRounds = CInt(team.Element("ByeRounds")),
            .tpPlayerA = players("A"),
            .tpPlayerB = players("B"),
            .tpPlayerC = players("C")
        } _
    ).ToList()
```

Here's the creation of the `xd` that I used for testing:

```
    Dim xd = XDocument.Parse("<Tournament TeamPlayers=""1"">
    <Teams>
        <Team>
            <TeamID>0</TeamID>
            <TeamName>Sample</TeamName>
            <Status>10</Status>
            <Memo>Sample Team</Memo>
            <ByeRounds>0</ByeRounds>
            <Players>
                <Player>
                    <MemberNumber>1</MemberNumber>
                    <MemberName>Dummy</MemberName>
                    <PlayerFirstName>Test</PlayerFirstName>
                    <PlayerLastName>User</PlayerLastName>
                    <SeatOrder>A</SeatOrder>
                </Player>
                <Player>
                    <MemberNumber></MemberNumber>
                    <MemberName></MemberName>
                    <PlayerFirstName></PlayerFirstName>
                    <PlayerLastName></PlayerLastName>
                    <SeatOrder>B</SeatOrder>
                </Player>
                <Player>
                    <MemberNumber></MemberNumber>
                    <MemberName></MemberName>
                    <PlayerFirstName></PlayerFirstName>
                    <PlayerLastName></PlayerLastName>
                    <SeatOrder>C</SeatOrder>
                </Player>
            </Players>
        </Team>
    </Teams>
</Tournament>")
```

I'd also suggest changing your classes to use the standard naming conventions for .NET.

```
Public Class TournamentTeam
    Public Name As String
    Public ID As Integer
    Public ByeRounds As Integer
    Public Status As Integer
    Public Memo As String
    Public PlayerA As PlayerInfo
    Public PlayerB As PlayerInfo
    Public PlayerC As PlayerInfo
End Class

Public Class PlayerInfo
    Public MembershipName As String
    Public MembershipNo As String
    Public FirstName As String
    Public LastName As String
    Public SeatOrder As String
End Class
```

Finally, I'd also look at removing the three `Player` properties and put a dictionary in instead.

If it's always `A`, `B`, and `C` then use an `Enum` as the key, otherwise use a `String`.

```
Public Class TournamentTeam
    Public Name As String
    Public ID As Integer
    Public ByeRounds As Integer
    Public Status As Integer
    Public Memo As String
    Public Players As Dictionary(Of PlayerSeat, PlayerInfo)
End Class

Public Enum PlayerSeat
    A
    B
    C
End Enum

Public Class PlayerInfo
    Public MembershipName As String
    Public MembershipNo As String
    Public FirstName As String
    Public LastName As String
    Public SeatOrder As String
End Class
```

Then your code would be:

```
    Dim lstOutputTeams As List(Of TournamentTeam) = _
    ( _
        From team In xd.Root.Element("Teams").Elements("Team") _
        Select New TournamentTeam() With _
        {
            .ID = CInt(team.Element("TeamID")),
            .Name = CStr(team.Element("TeamName")),
            .Status = CInt(team.Element("Status")),
            .Memo = CStr(team.Element("Memo")),
            .ByeRounds = CInt(team.Element("ByeRounds")),
            .Players = team.Element("Players").Elements("Player").Select(Function(player) _
            New PlayerInfo() With _
            {
                .MembershipName = player.Element("MemberName").Value,
                .MembershipNo = player.Element("MemberNumber").Value,
                .FirstName = player.Element("PlayerFirstName").Value,
                .LastName = player.Element("PlayerLastName").Value,
                .SeatOrder = player.Element("SeatOrder").Value
            }).ToDictionary(Function(x) CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(PlayerSeat), x.SeatOrder), PlayerSeat))
        } _
    ).ToList()
```

Comment: This does help, thank you. And if you want to see what the full Tournament XML file looks like, including why I *HAVE* to recursively go through everything: https://pastebin.com/QNtPXFxG

Comment: @PaulWilliams - ***Why you had to recursively go through everything*** should have been in the question.

Comment: @PaulWilliams - Having just looked at the file there is nothing recursive in there.

Comment: Got ya. Semantics aside, I did manage to get the code to work separately, but I'll go back and match it to yours. I was trying to avoid using For Loops which your code does well.

Comment: @PaulWilliams - When you say "semantics", did you mean something other than recursive?

Comment: I think I meant iterating through the various lists. Which is what your code does. (To go through each item in the XML and add them to the lists.)

Comment: @PaulWilliams - That's not recursion at all then.